# AWS SNS multiple subscribers by code (e.g. dynamic instances)

Tags: asp.net, .net, amazon-web-services, amazon-sqs, amazon-sns

Maybe somebody can help me to find a better solution with AWS infrastructure.

I will have N services (each service is an instance) (at least min 1, the others will add dynamically). In the memory of each service, there is a data cache (1-3Gb). I need to implement a publisher-subscriber pattern to update the cache on each service. As I see AWS SNS can call SQS, AWS Lambda, http\https, SMS and etc. So, looks like AWS SNS is not supporting subscribe\unsubscribe to SNS from code.

For now, I see only one solution:

1. when a new instance is starting it will create an SQS queue and subscribe this SQS to the existing SNS topic
2. when the instance is terminating it will unsubscribe the SQS queue from the SNS topic and then delete SQS
3. so, each instance will receive an event via SQS about cache update.

I do not like this solution, bc I need to store access keys with create\edit rights for SQS and SNS.

So, maybe somebody can advise me of another solution? I will be really appreciated any ideas.

P.S. I can't use cache like ElasticCache or Redis, because load data and deserialization take (3-5 seconds) but from memory, it takes 0.5 seconds.
I'm using .net core 3.x version

Answer (score 0):

The solution you outlined is typically what most people end up using (one SQS queue + subscription per host with setup and tear down).

Keep in mind that you can scope down IAM policies to only apply to certain resources, e.g. only subscribe/unsubscribe to one particular SNS topic. You could also consider doing the setup/tear down as part of the scale up/scale down process rather than in the instances themselves.

Comment: yes, i think the same, but i created this post to double-check and maybe somebody implements another solution. Thank you for your involvement!